# JCanvas: How do I get the size of an Image?

Tags: javascript, jcanvas

I have drawn an image like this:

```
$("canvas").drawImage({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        source: src,
        draggable: true,
        layer: true,
        name: "image",
        fromCenter: false,
    }
});
```

The image shows as it should. It is larger than the screen and I want to draw a much smaller rect (by the factor of .05) the sides of which are proportionate to the original image. How do I retrieve width and height of the above image?

I tried:

```
var imageWidth = $("canvas").getLayer("image").width;
var imageHeight = $("canvas").getLayer("image").height;
```

But `alert($("canvas").getLayer("image").width);` returns `null`. I also tried:

```
var imageWidth = $("canvas").getCanvasImage.width;
var imageHeight = $("canvas").getCanvasImage.height;
```

But `alert($("canvas").getCanvasImage.width);` returns `undefined`.

Comment: I don't know this library, but playing a bit with their playground, it seems you can retrieve it under the `load` event parameter, if no width and height options were set, under the sWidth and sHeight properties of the passed parameter. Sounds weird it disappears when you set width and height options though, I probably won't go further into this library ;-)

Comment: Ps: Here is the link to the [playground I used](http://projects.calebevans.me/jcanvas/sandbox/?code=Ly8gRnVuY3Rpb24gZm9yIGRyYXdpbmcgYW4gYXJjCmZ1bmN0aW9uIGFyYyhlKSB7CiAgY29uc29sZS5sb2coZS5zV2lkdGgsIGUuc0hlaWdodCk7CiAgJCgnY2FudmFzJykuZHJhd0FyYyh7CiAgICBzdHJva2VTdHlsZTogJyM2ZjknLAogICAgc3Ryb2tlV2lkdGg6IDQsCiAgICB4OiAxNTUsIHk6IDE1NSwKICAgIHJhZGl1czogNDAKICB9KTsKfQoKLy8gUnVuIHRoZSBhcmMoKSBmdW5jdGlvbiBhZnRlciB0aGUgaW1hZ2UgaGFzIGxvYWRlZAokKCdjYW52YXMnKS5kcmF3SW1hZ2UoewogIHNvdXJjZTogJ2ltYWdlcy9sYWR5YnVnLmpwZycsCiAgeDogMTUwLCB5OiAxNTAsCiAgbG9hZDogYXJjCn0pOw==)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have to wait for the loading of the image to finish, before I can retrieve its properties. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use below statement to get height and width of canvas image

```js
var imageWidth = $("canvas").width();
var imageHeight = $("canvas").height();
```

Comment: this will return the computed width and height of the canvas element, not the ones of the image